# Lazy type constraint (implement Rust `Default` trait in c++)

Tags: c++, type-constraints

In Rust you can implement traits for structs and each implementation has own type constraint. (for who may does not familiar with rust, you can consider a "trait" as a "base class" and "implementation" as "inheritance").
look at this example:

```rust
// our struct has an item of type mutable T pointer
struct Box<T> {
    inner: mut* T
} 

// implementing `Default` trait for 
// box. in this implementation, type 
// constraint is: `T: Default`. 
// it means the inner type also must 
// implements Default. 
impl <T: Default> for Box<T> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        return Box::new(T::default());
    }
}
```

the note in this example is there is no need `T: Default` to be applied until you use `Box::default()` in your code.

well it is possible to do like this in cpp? I'm familiar with how we can constraint types in cpp and this is not my problem. I want to know is there some way to `lazy type constrain` (maybe a better description) in cpp when I define a class?

I know it is possible with `if constexpr` or `static_assert`. but this way is not beautiful.
I want a `template` or `concept` solution ( I mean what applies to function signature in fact) if possible.
thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I follow exactly what you want (I don't really know Rust), but you can constrain member functions individually:

```
template<typename T>
concept Default = requires {
    { T::default_() } -> std::same_as<T>;
};

template<typename T>
struct Box {
    static Box default_()
    requires Default<T> {
        //...
    }
    //...
};
```

Now `Box` itself has no requirements on `T`, but to use `Box::default()` will require `T` to satisfy the `Default` concept.

However, it would basically work without the constraint as well. If `Box<T>::default` calls `T::default()` and the latter is not well-formed the code will fail to compile if and only if `Box<T>::default` is actually used in a way that requires it to be defined (i.e. called or pointer/reference to it taken). But without the `requires` clause e.g. `Default<Box<T>>` would always report `true`.

And of course in C++ we would use the default constructor instead of a static member function called `default` to construct the object. The same approach applies to constructors though and there is already the concept `std::default_initializable` for that in the standard library.

As far as I understand, Rust traits do not really overlap fully with either C++ (abstract) base classes nor concepts though. The approach above will not allow for runtime polymorphism on types satisfying `Default`. For that an abstract base class with the interface functions as non-static pure virtual member functions should be used instead.

However, the trait `Default` only imposes a requirement on a static member function, so that it shouldn't be relevant to runtime polymorphism, but only compile-time properties of the type, which is what concepts are for, although in contrast to Rust you don't declare a type to implement a trait. Instead the concept describes requirements which a type needs to satisfy to satisfy the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done with concepts:

```
#include <concepts>

template<std::default_initializable  T>
struct Box {};

struct Yes{};

struct No{ No(int){}}; // No default ctor
int main()
{
    Box<Yes> y;
    Box<No> n;
}
```

which outputs:

```
<source>:14:11: error: template constraint failure for 'template<class T>  requires  default_initializable<T> struct Box'
   14 |     Box<No> n;
      |           ^
<source>:14:11: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/concepts: In substitution of 'template<class T>  requires  default_initializable<T> struct Box [with T = No]':
<source>:14:11:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/concepts:136:13:   required for the satisfaction of 'constructible_from<_Tp>' [with _Tp = No]
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/concepts:141:13:   required for the satisfaction of 'default_initializable<T>' [with T = No]
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/concepts:137:30: note: the expression 'is_constructible_v<_Tp, _Args ...> [with _Tp = No; _Args = {}]' evaluated to 'false'
  137 |       = destructible<_Tp> && is_constructible_v<_Tp, _Args...>;
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

`Box<Yes>` will compile without issues. The above is a shorthand for the following which allows to chain more requirements

```
template<typename  T>
requires std::default_initializable<T>
struct Box { };
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>

class SomeBaseClass {};

template<typename T>
concept Derived = std::is_base_of_v<SomeBaseClass, T>;

template<typename T>
concept Default = requires(T) {
    { T::by_default() } -> std::convertible_to<T>;
};

template<Derived T>
class Box {
    T* inner;

    Box(T data): (&data);

  public:
    static Box by_default() 
    requires(Default<T>) {  // This was my lost!
        return Box(T::by_default());
    }
};


class Object: SomeBaseClass {
  public:
    static Object by_default() {
        return Object();
    }
};


int main() {
    Box<Object> b = Box<Object>::by_default();
}
```